# Haskell Freestate evaluate to State

Tags: haskell, state

I have a datatype called FreeState;

```
data FreeState s a = 
      Get (s -> FreeState s a)
    | Put s (FreeState s a)
    | Return a
```

Now I need to evaluate this FreeState to a State;

```
eval :: FreeState s a -> State s a
```

I do not think I understand States enough to do this. Can someone enlighten me, in the hope I understand States better.

I have now

```
eval :: FreeState s a -> State s a
eval (Put s z) = State (\_ -> (fst (runState (eval z) s), s))
eval (Get z) = State (\s -> (fst $ (runState (eval (z s)) s), s))
eval (Return a) = State (\s -> (a, s))
```

Would this be correct?

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FreeState` data type is essentially just a data type that encodes `State` operations, so we can "decode" this into a `State` with:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy (State, get, put)

eval :: FreeState s a -> State s a
eval (Get f) = get >>= eval . f
eval (Put v f) = put v >> eval f
eval (Return a) = return a
```

As for the attempt, the line:

```
State (\_ -> (fst (runState (eval z) s), s))
```

you probably here swapped the order of the parameters, since this is normally `s -> (s, a)`, but even if we swap the order of the parameters, this is not correct since it means you "inject" the value as new state, run the rest `z` and then use `s` as state again, but it is possible that `z` will further alter the state.

Comment: You can evaluate it to anything that uses the state interface, by generalizing the type: `FreeState a b -> MonadState a m => m b`